# Spark Streaming with PubSub-NullPointerException while streaming from pub sub in java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spark-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

My data is in PubSub and i want to stream the data.I use dataproc to run my spark job in java.But the job fails with following error.

19/06/18 06:32:30 WARN org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Error reported by receiver for stream 0: Failed to pull messages - java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper.iterator(Wrappers.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:590)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.pubsub.PubsubReceiver.receive(PubsubInputDStream.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.pubsub.PubsubReceiver$$anon$1.run(PubsubInputDStream.scala:247)

the code segment i used is

PubsubUtils.createStream(jssc, "projectId","TopicName","subscriptionName",new SparkGCPCredentials.Builder().jsonServiceAccount("absolute path to json placed in dataproc"), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());

Answer (score 1):

This warning shows up when spark tries to read events from a pubsub subscription with no waiting events. It should not break the job, but only means that there were no events to be read for a given batch of data.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid it?